# Why the + in my text area is replaced with a space when I send it to nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a text area that has the following text:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a, b;
 cin >> a >> b;
  cout << a + b;
}
```

I send the above text to nodejs server through a POST request. When I print request.body it replaces the "+" sign with a " ". I don't know why this happens? How can I fix that?

request.body is exactly like that ignoring the "+":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a, b;
 cin >> a >> b;
  cout << a   b;
}
```

Client code:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
        console.log(`data is ${data}`);
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(data);
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/', data)
        .then(response =>  {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

Here is the express code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const testCode = require('./test');
const port = 3001;


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// ------------------------------------

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
  });
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const code = Object.keys(req.body)[0];
  console.log(code);
  
  res.send(testCode(code));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Comment: Help please, I'm stuck.

Comment: please share your `testCode` method

Comment: also share the raw request body you are sending from client

Comment: @AmirSaleem plus is replaced with spaces in `code` variable, so `testCode` isn't the case.